# Stripping single and double quotes in a string using bash / standard Linux commands only

Tags: linux, bash, quotes, quoting

I'm looking for something that will translate a string as follows, using only bash / standard Linux commands:

1. Single-quotes surrounding a string should be removed
2. Double-quotes surrounding a string should be removed
3. Unquoted strings should remain the same
4. Strings with unmatched surrounding quotes should remain the same
5. Single-quotes that don't surround the string should remain
6. Double-quotes that don't surround the string should remain

For example:

- 'Food' should become Food
- "Food" should become Food
- Food should remain the same
- 'Food" should remain the same
- "Food' should remain the same
- 'Fo'od' should become Fo'od
- "Fo'od" should become Fo'od
- Fo'od should remain the same
- 'Fo"od' should become Fo"od
- "Fo"od" should become Fo"od
- Fo"od should remain the same

Thank you!

Comment: +1 for all of those acceptance tests!

Comment: As most "customers" do, an extra one's been added afterwards that wasn't in the original set :-)

Comment: So.. backslash escapes are meaningless?

"Food\" -> Food\ ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This should do it:

```
sed "s/^\([\"']\)\(.*\)\1\$/\2/g" in.txt
```

Where in.txt is:

```
"Fo'od'
'Food'
"Food"
"Fo"od'
Food
'Food"
"Food'
'Fo'od'
"Fo'od"
Fo'od
'Fo"od'
"Fo"od"
Fo"od
```

And expected.txt is:

```
"Fo'od'
Food
Food
"Fo"od'
Food
'Food"
"Food'
Fo'od
Fo'od
Fo'od
Fo"od
Fo"od
Fo"od
```

You can check they match with:

```
diff -s <(sed "s/^\([\"']\)\(.*\)\1\$/\2/g" in.txt) expected.txt
```

Comment: Very close :-)

echo \"fo\"bar\' | sed "s/\([\"']\)\(.*\)\1/\2/g"

Got: fobar'

Expected: "fo"bar'

Comment: Great! Just go changing the requirements after the coding is done ;-) updated for that case.

Comment: Here's one final requirements change :-)

echo \"fo\'bar\' | sed -e "s/\([\"']\)\(.*\)\1\$/\2/g"

Got: "fobar

Expected: "fo'bar'

Comment: I hate regular expressions now.

Comment: +1 for an entertaining contest. :) Deleting my proven-to-be-dodgy sed post accordingly.

Comment: +1 for proving that 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.' Is as true as it gets!

Comment: This is a good regex - but the backslash infront of the $ is unnecessary.  It could just be sed "s/^\([\"']\)\(.*\)\1$/\2/g" in.txt

Comment: @e_m0ney you're right. I always escape $ inside "" as in most cases it will get misinterpreted as a variable. This is one case where it does not (but escaping it doesn't harm either).

Comment: good point @richq when doing $ inside quotes it will be interpreted as a variable. Although for all cases when writing regex in sed and matching EOL char, you should generally be safe because the next character will be a "/".  Either way, no harm done and its safe.  Good call

Answer (score 25):

You could use `tr`:

```
echo "$string" | tr -d 'chars to delete'
```

... also works, however 'tr' is known to be problematic on much older (circa Redhat 9-ish) distributions. `tr` is an abbreviation for 'translate', commonly used in pipes to transform input. The `-d` option simply means 'delete'.

Most modern versions also contain predefined macros to transform upper to lower, lower to upper, kill white space, etc. Hence, if you use it, take a second to poke at what else it does (see the help output / man page), comes in handy.

Answer (score 17):

```
VAR="'FOOD'"

VAR=$(eval echo $VAR)
```

Explanation: Since quotes are already understood by the shell you can ask the shell to evaluate a command that just echos the quoted string, the same way it does when you type it yourself.

Here, `eval echo $VAR` expands to `eval echo 'FOOD'` because the quotes are actually part of the value of `VAR`. If you were to run `echo 'FOOD'` into the shell you'd get `FOOD` (without the quotes). That's what `eval` does: it takes its input and runs it like a shell command.

> #### ⚠CODE INJECTION!
>
> `eval` expose scripts to code injection.
>
> ```
> VAR=';ls -l'
>
> VAR=$(eval echo $VAR)
> ```
>
> will cause execution of `ls -l`.
>
> Much more harmful codes could be injected here.

Comment: please add some explanation too!!

Comment: I added some explanation and modernized the example a bit.

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to use **sed**...

```
echo $mystring | sed -s "s/^\(\(\"\(.*\)\"\)\|\('\(.*\)'\)\)\$/\\3\\5/g"
```

Comment: I have not idea if it works, but +1 for the awesomeness of your sed command :)

Comment: This is very close, but just a teeny bit off.

echo \"fo\"bar\' | sed -s "s/^\(\"\(.*\)\"\)\|\(\'\(.*\)\'\)\$/\\2/g"

Got: fobar'

Expected: "fo"bar'

Comment: Yes... for some reason I can't fathom, the last $ stubbornly refuses to match the end of my string. Working on it...

Comment: Also, quote your parameter expansion.

Answer (score 4):

Just using Bash builtins (i.e. Bash parameter expansion):

```
IFS=' ' 

food_strings=( "'Food'" '"Food"' Food "'Food\"" "\"Food'" "'Fo'od'" "\"Fo'od\"" "Fo'od" "'Fo\"od'" '"Fo"od"' 'Fo"od'  )  

for food in ${food_strings[@]}; do 

   [[ "${food#\'}" != "$food" ]] && [[ "${food%\'}" != "$food" ]] && { food="${food#\'}"; food="${food%\'}"; } 

   [[ "${food#\"}" != "$food" ]] && [[ "${food%\"}" != "$food" ]] && { food="${food#\"}"; food="${food%\"}"; } 

   echo "$food"

done
```

For yet another example of Bash parameter expansion see:

http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1816

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled upon this as well. For the first three test cases, `eval echo $string` works well. To get it to work for all cases requested and a few others, I came up with this (tested with `bash` and `dash`):

```
#!/bin/sh

stripquotes() {
    local firstchar="`substr "$1" 0 1`"
    local len=${#1}
    local ilast=$((${#1} - 1))
    local lastchar="`substr "$1" $(($len - 1))`"
    if [ "$firstchar" = '"' ] || [ "$firstchar" = "'" ] && [ $firstchar = $lastchar ]; then
        echo "`substr "$1" 1 $(($len - 2))`"
    else
        echo "$1"
    fi
}

# $1 = String.
# $2 = Start index.
# $3 = Length (optional). If unspecified or an empty string, the length of the
#      rest of the string is used.
substr() {
    local "len=$3"
    [ "$len" = '' ] && len=${#1}
    if ! (echo ${1:$2:$len}) 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "$1" | awk "{ print(substr(\$0, $(($2 + 1)), $len)) }"
    fi
}

var="'Food'"
stripquotes "$var"

var='"Food"'
stripquotes "$var"

var=Food
stripquotes "$var"

var=\'Food\"
stripquotes "$var"

var=\"Food\'
stripquotes "$var"

var="'Fo'od'"
stripquotes "$var"

var="\"Fo'od\""
stripquotes "$var"

var="Fo'od"
stripquotes "$var"

var="'Fo\"od'"
stripquotes "$var"

var="\"Fo\"od\""
stripquotes "$var"

var="Fo\"od"
stripquotes "$var"

# A string with whitespace should work too.
var="'F\"o 'o o o' o\"d'"
stripquotes "$var"

# Strings that start and end with the same character that isn't a quote or
# doublequote should stay the same.
var="TEST"
stripquotes "$var"

# An empty string should not cause errors.
var=
stripquotes "$var"

# Strings of length 2 that begin and end with a quote or doublequote should not
# cause errors.
var="''"
stripquotes "$var"
var='""'
stripquotes "$var"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
python -c "import sys;a=sys.stdin.read();a=a.strip();print (a[1:-1] if a[0]==a[-1] and a[0] in \"'\\\"\" else a)"
```

it doesn't handle edge cases extremely well (such as an empty string), but it will serve as a starting point. It works by striping the front and back character if they are the same and if they are ' or "

Comment: Jason explicitly said that he wants bash / standard Linux commands.

Even though python is shipped with most of the commonly used distros, it is certainly not standard. If you install a basic Debian system, for example, it doesn't include python.