# String variable output showing strange Single Quote in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, glusterfs

I have following scripts

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o xtrace
gluster_volume="a.example.com:/data/brick1/gv0 b.example.com:/data/brick1/gv0"
gluster volume create gv0 replica 2 ${gluster_volume} force
```

While executing second line this script throwing error related to gluster_volume that its unable read complete line and just considering  `a.example.com:/data/brick1/gv0 b.example.com`(so look like gluster command not able parse it).

Then I run this script with trace and found that command is like

```
gluster volume create gv0 replica 2 'a.example.com:/data/brick1/gv0 b.example.com:/data/brick1/gv0' force
```

so script is adding single quotes which are creating problem. I was under the impression that it's due to `set -o xtrace` the single quotes are not part of the value, just part of the displayed command line. But its not true. if i run above command on command prompt it gives same error and on removing quotes it works.

How i can change my script so it don't add quotes? (I tried to remove quote with sed but not working, something happening at run time).

I need `gluster_volume` with dynamic values.

**Update1:**

```
workers=`echo "${WORKER_HOST_IP}"|sed "s/,$//"`
IFS=','
for worker in ${workers}; do
    IFS='-' read -r -a array <<< "$worker"

    gluster_volume+=${array[0]}':/data/brick1/gv0 '

done
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733338/shell-script-remove-first-and-last-quote-from-a-variable

Comment: Another option might be using the eval command... just concat the string to form the entire command, first. https://linuxhint.com/bash_eval_command/

Comment: I suspect that you are not using `bash` but `zsh`. Add this to your script and its output to your question: `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`. How do you start your script?

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy Thanks eval works for me.

Comment: @Cyrus I am calling this script from other like `sh myscript.sh`

Comment: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Replace `sh` with `bash`.

Comment: @Cyrus bash doesn't helped so i will use eval it works for me thanks.

Comment: I'd avoid `eval` if at all possible -- it has a well-deserved reputation as a bug magnet. The single-quotes are just the shell's way of indicating that that string isn't being split up into separate arguments ("words"). I'd concentrate on trying to figure out *why* it isn't being split.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for highlighting it look like gluster bug as its not able to parse, i will raise accordingly.

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan I don't think it can be `gluster` -- the shell should perform word splitting before passing the arguments to `gluster`, so it has to be happening at the shell level. The only things I can think of that'd cause this are that you're running `zsh` as the shell, or that the `IFS` variable has been set to some unusual value. It sounds like you've eliminated `zsh`; is it possible something has messed with `IFS`?

Comment: @GordonDavisson For sake of simplicity i provided trimmed code previously, Now i shared the code which is using IFS to make gluster_volume variable, you can see updated code under update1

Comment: That `IFS=','` explains it. You could reset `IFS` back to normal after the loop (there are several ways to do this, none perfect), but I'd look at using a better method to split `workers`. The best way to do that depends on the exact format of the `WORKER_HOST_IP` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `eval`(Be careful if the list of bricks or the string comes from an external untrusted source)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -o xtrace
gluster_volume="a.example.com:/data/brick1/gv0 b.example.com:/data/brick1/gv0"
eval "gluster volume create gv0 replica 2 ${gluster_volume} force"
```